# How to set font and size of JTable for print

Tags: java, printing, jtable

I am trying to print invoice bill for POS. I want to print JTable and some of JComponent. I am using Epson printer but it prints a long sheet. How can I change the size of table to print? This is the code I use:

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("welcome ");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("thank for fisit");
try {
     PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
     set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

     jTable2.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer, false, set, false);
     jTextField8.print();


 } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "Error from Printer Job "
            + "\n" + e);   
 }
```

Comment: Please put more clear: what you curently have (the connection between jTable and jTextField28 is missing), the current outcome you see (this is not clear), and the outcome you expect (also not clear).

Comment: the jtable is connected to database and the jtext display the total price with   this method of print the print ok when i use A4 paper but i want to use the role paper so is there any way to Decreasing the size of table before printing